# Facebook send dialog TypeError

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a button on facebook app that a user can use to send a link to his or her friends.

This is the code that calls the facebook send dialog.

```
 onclick="FB.ui({
  method: \'send\',
  link: \'https://whatever.com',
  caption: \'An example caption\'
}, function(response){});"
```

The code seems to work once but after that i get an error in the console

`"sending to: https://s-static.ak.facebook.com (ff29e88e01f6fe_https)" debug.js:3278:4
TypeError: windowRef is null debug.js:5285:12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. The problem was that i was loading the button through ajax and facebook dosn't seem to like that. When i put the button directly into the app it works.